# using buscape api to get list of products in all the pages

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby on rails so this pretty difficult for me.

I am using the [buscape api](https://github.com/devbuscapecompany/buscape-ruby) to get list of products but i only get the products from the first page but I need all the products from every page. Any suggestions on how i can do this?

Comment: You can delete this post and post it there.

Comment: @Quincunx yea i am doing that

Comment: What? This guy deleted his account, not this post...

Comment: Perhaps the embarrassment was too much for him?

Comment: Or he didn't realise that you only need one account SE-wide.

Answer (score 0):

man.

I created a magento module that can help you:

https://github.com/jaimeneto85/sitemap-xml-generator

You will can integrate your magento on buscape and any other marketing channel using XML.